# Sending integers between android intents

Tags: android

From mainActivity I am trying to access a global variable inside of an intent named Game_Mode. But I am getting an error that tells me it does not exist.`

```
if(player==1){
        startActivity(Game_Mode);
        type=Game_Mode.type;}
```

This is in the MainActivity

```
Intent Game_Mode = new Intent(this, Game_Mode.class);
    Intent two_three = new Intent(this, Two_three.class);

    player = game.connect("sslab02.cs.purdue.edu", 5432);
    player=1;
    if(player==1){
        startActivity(Game_Mode);
        type=Game_Mode.type;
```

This is in Game_Mode

```
public class Game_Mode extends ActionBarActivity {
int mode = 1;
int size = 1;
static int type = 0;
```

Comment: is public and static?

Comment: in the Game_Mode it is public

Comment: It should be static too.

Comment: so in my Game_Mode it is now static int type = #; where # is a real number but in the main which is shown above it is still not resolving to a field

Comment: Yeah. now it should work. Can you add the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
static int type = 0;
```

`type` is not public but `package-level`, so make it `public` using `public` keyword.

```
public static int type = 0;
```

Anyway the problem here is inside this code block

```
Intent Game_Mode = new Intent(this, Game_Mode.class);
Intent two_three = new Intent(this, Two_three.class);

player = game.connect("sslab02.cs.purdue.edu", 5432);
player=1;
if(player==1){
    startActivity(Game_Mode);
    type=Game_Mode.type;
```

You have an `intent` variable named `Game_Mode` (the same name of the class), so when you do `Game_Mode.type` it checks the field in the `Intent` class not in your class. The best way to fix it is to simple rename it to something else:

```
Intent gameMode = new Intent(this, Game_Mode.class);
Intent two_Three = new Intent(this, Two_three.class);// here too you could call it twoThree

player = game.connect("sslab02.cs.purdue.edu", 5432);
player=1;
if(player==1){
    startActivity(gameMode);
    type=Game_Mode.type;
```

Following Java conventions about names too.

---

Anyway, if you need to pass data between Activity you should use `Extras`.

Comment: What you told me works. The issue I am having now is that I change type later in the game_Mode but my main is going and getting it right away so it is always 0 any thoughts

Comment: when you change it inside Game_Mode, everytime you do Game_Mode.type you will see the updated value. But with type = Game_Mode.type; you get the value and stop.

Comment: So how might i go about having it wait to get the new value, i have tried using startActivityForResult but it does not work

Comment: you could use an interface to get called the callback when the value is ready

Answer (score 0):

I honestly recommend to use SharedPreferences in order to store and retrieve application-level variables, since they're really secure and robust.

Answer (score 0):

The Game_Mode is a class and you have created an intent in the name of the class.

```
Intent Game_Mode = new Intent(this, Game_Mode.class);
```

Please concentrate on that one.